# Proxy Auto Configuration

Tags: tfs, proxy

I have configured our local tfs proxy against the Active Directory site for our local office using the below syntax:

```
tf proxy /add http://MyProxy:8080 /default:site /Site:LocalOffice /name:MyProxy
```

When I run

```
tf proxy /configure
```

it correctly identifies my site, and sets up the correct proxy.

However, I'm seeing inconsistent behaviour during `get` operations.

My understanding is that when run a `get` operation (either via `tf get` or through Visual Studio), it should automatically recognise that the site has a proxy, and configure it.

When I tried this on a VM that had never used a proxy, this seems to have worked fine. However, on my own machine, I went into VS and removed the proxy settings, then closed the VS instance. Then I attempted a `tf get` from powershell, and found that it did not configure the proxy correctly (I confirmed using `tf proxy`).

I'm expecting the proxy to be automatically configured for any user who is currently in our office, overriding any manual settings they have. Is there additional setup I need to do in order to do this?

**Update**

Based on the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791981%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I would expect it to set up the proxy on a my machine when I ask for the code

> If you add a proxy record with the default set to site, the first time that a developer from within the specified Active Directory domain performs a get operation, Team Foundation Server will redirect that developer's request to the proxy that is specified by the record that is associated with the site.

However, this doesn't happen even if I clear out the proxy settings in VC (and untick the box) and perform a get after a reboot. I can understand it perhaps not overriding a setting I enter by hand, but I would expect it to configure when no setting is present at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the /default flag:

```
tf proxy /add http://MyProxy:8080 /default:site /Site:LocalOffice
```

A full description of how this works can be found on: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepakkhare/archive/2014/05/06/tfs-proxy-unsung-hero.aspx

Comment: ok, so I can understand it respecting my values if i manually override the settings, but I've cleared the proxy values, and unticked the box in VS. Even after a restart it doesn't auto-configure the proxy, which is contrary to my understanding of the documentation. I've updated the question with the documentation.

Comment: Besides, the point of configuring settings by AD site, is to allow different sites to use local proxies, and users moving between sites would automatically receive the correct settings for where they were that day. Are you suggesting that they have to run `tf proxy /configure` every time the go into a different office?

Comment: Hmm. I tried it with that too (also with /name) but it didn't seem to make any difference.